# Using "look" without preposition

Tags: grammar, prepositions, sentence-meaning

I came across with this sentence where "look" was used without preposition afterward. Isn't ***both ways*** a noun phrase ? In the other sentences "look" was used before a preposition so what is the different between them ?

1- ***Be careful to look both ways when you cross the road.***

The other examples :

2- They looked ***at*** the picture and laughed.

3- Look ***at*** all these toys on the floor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In "Look both ways," *both ways* is more an adverbial phrase, adverting to a position.

It's parallel to using *up* after *look*. If you say "Look up," *up* is an adverb.

> **up** *adv*
>   1 a. In or to a higher position: *looking up*.
>   <sub>[TFD Online](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/up)</sub>

Comment: Yeah, it's really more about indicating the direction or location to look.